# Powerquery: how to convert/cast type Type to type Text?

Tags: types, powerbi, metadata, powerquery

Ho to extract text from Type item an vice versa?

In theory, it's  `Text.From` function functionality, but it doesn't work... - "`Expression.Error: We cannot convert Type to Text type.`
"

**Example**: how to get `ClmType2` from `ClmType1` and vice versa through query

```
let 
    srcTbl = Table.FromRows(
        {
            {1, "Bob", "Smith", "123-4567"},
            {2, "Jim", "Brown", "987-6543"},
            {3, "Paul", "Wick", "543-7890"}
        },
        {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Phone"}    
    ),
    
    Source = Table.FromList(Table.ColumnNames(srcTbl),null,{"NmClm"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ClmType1", each if [NmClm]="CustomerID" then "Int16.Type" else "text"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "ClmType2", each if [NmClm]="CustomerID" then Int64.Type else type text)
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

[image]

**?**

**Related Topics:**

1. [PowerQuery: How to get Column type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73976658/6165594)
2. [Powerquery: how to convert/cast type Type to type Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73946747/6165594)
3. [PowerQuery: type definition, difference between Table.Scema fields
   [TypeName] and [Kind]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73984300/6165594)

Comment: Check out `Type.Facets`. There's also `Table.Schema` if you need to do this for a table as a whole. Converting type names to actual types gets a little ugly -- you'll need `Expression.Evaluate("type ...")`. Note that none of this is really needed if you just need to conditionally convert values to particular types, that can be done in many other ways, including `Value.As`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, suggested functions doesn't work for me. In my project `ClmType2` column works fine, but I want to see values in Metatable as in `ClmType1`. By other words, `ClmType2`  type is pc friendly, but NOT user/developer friendly as `ClmType1` and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this ([or download file](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/main/Questions/type2text.pbix)):

function `fnType2Text`:

```
(_type)=> 
try 
    Value.Metadata(_type)[Documentation.Name]
otherwise
    Table.Schema(
        #table(type table [tmpVar = _type], {})
    )[Kind]{0}
```

function `fnText2Type`:

```
(_type as text)=> 
try     
    Expression.Evaluate("type "& _type) 
otherwise 
    Expression.Evaluate(
        _type,
        [ Int64.Type    = Int64.Type       
        , Int32.Type    = Int32.Type       
        , Int16.Type    = Int16.Type       
        , Number.Type   = Number.Type      
        , Date.Type     = Date.Type        
        , DateTime.Type = DateTime.Type            
        , Text.Type     = Text.Type    
        ]    
    )
```

[image]

Connected topics:

1. [How to get type for specified ColumnName in Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73976658/6165594)

P.S. Thanks to guys for ideas:

1. [Use Value.Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73948941/6165594)
2. [Use Table.Schema with empty table](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-print-out-quot-type-text-quot-or-quot-type-number-quot-as/m-p/1066203#M35660)

Answer (score 1):

There's got to be an easier way, but one method I came up with to derive `ClmType1` from `ClmType2`.

*Note that it differentiates between primitive and complex types using Metadata.*

```
//I believe that primitive types don't have metadata attached.
   #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "text from ClmType2", each 
        try Value.Metadata([ClmType2])[Documentation.Name]
            otherwise 
                Table.Schema(
                    Table.TransformColumnTypes(
                        Table.FromColumns({{null}}),{"Column1", [ClmType2]}))[Kind]{0})
```

[image]

Comment: Ron, do you know how to perform reverse operation:  
something like `= Table.AddColumn(Source, "text2type", each [ClmType1], type type)`  
?

Comment: @Denis Yes, but I see you have already accepted an answer.

Comment: If you have better idea please feel free to edit proposed solution in accepted post