# PowerQuery: How to get Column type?

Tags: function, types, powerbi, metadata, powerquery

How to get type for specified ColumnName in Table?

**Example**: How to get `type text` for column `FirstName`:
[image]

Table code:

```
= Table.FromRows(
        {
            {1, "Bob", "Smith", "123-4567"},
            {2, "Jim", "Brown", "987-6543"},
            {3, "Paul", "Wick", "543-7890"}
        },
        {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Phone"}    
    )
```

P.S. Solution as function strongly appreciated! :)

**Related Topics:**

1. [PowerQuery: How to get Column type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73976658/6165594)
2. [Powerquery: how to convert/cast type Type to type Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73946747/6165594)
3. [PowerQuery: type definition, difference between Table.Scema fields
   [TypeName] and [Kind]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73984300/6165594)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of **Type.TableColumn** and **Value.Type** functions:

```
Type.TableColumn(Value.Type(TableName),ColumnName)
```

Comment: And how does one get the type of all columns at the same time?   Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try this function `sfnClmType` ([download](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/main/Questions/getColumnType.pbix)):

```
(TableName as table, ColumnName as text)    => 
let valTypeTxt = Table.SelectRows(Table.Schema(TableName), each [Name] = ColumnName){0}[Kind]
in  Expression.Evaluate("type "& valTypeTxt)
```

[image]

Connected topics:

1. [How to convert/cast type Type to type Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73948985/6165594)

Comment: I believe your code will only return the primitive types.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, on one hand, I understand what you mean, but on other hand, items with type `Type` can't contain values such `Int64.Type`  ;)  . Please look for more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73984301/6165594)

Comment: I suppose if that's not what he really means he will post a comment.