# PowerQuery: type definition, difference between Table.Scema fields [TypeName] and [Kind]

Tags: types, powerbi, metadata, powerquery

Why there is so annoying difference in `type` definition syntax:

1. Sometimes `powerquery` defines type using `type` keyword (like `type text` for text)
2. But sometimes it uses syntax with **NO** `type` keyword (like `Int64.Type` for text)

?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, didn't find the answer in Microsoft docs, but in my head it works as following:

1. Syntax with  keyword `type` defines   the Type (In `Table.Schema` ***Type*** = `[Kind]`)
2. Syntax with NO keyword type defines the subType (In `Table.Schema` ***subType*** = `[TypeName]`)

**Example1**: if you define type variable as subtype `Int16.Type`, in powerquery it displays it as type `number`:

[image]

**Example2**: If you define type as `number`, the subtype by default is `Number.Type`

```
let 
    Source = Table.FromRows({{1,11},{2,22}},{"Id1","Id2"}),
    typeNumber = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id1", type number}, {"Id2", Int64.Type}}),
    TableSchema = Table.Schema(typeNumber)[[Name],[Kind],[TypeName]]
in  TableSchema
```

[image]

[image]